# java math.​mxparser returns NaN when argument name is "e"

Tags: java, math, eval, evaluate

I use math.​mxparser to evaluate simple formula in java (j2ee) in java class,
Formula is store in database so for this example is "a+b+c", I mean in this formula "e" in not used,
But when any of my arguments named as "e" it returns "NaN" (Oh !)

```
            Argument a = new Argument("a = " + (jjNumber.isFloat(final_values_date_a.get(i).get("_val").toString()) ? final_values_date_a.get(i).get("_val").toString() : "0"));
            Argument b = new Argument("b = " + (jjNumber.isFloat(final_values_date_b.get(i).get("_val").toString()) ? final_values_date_b.get(i).get("_val").toString() : "0"));
            Argument c = new Argument("c = " + (jjNumber.isFloat(final_values_date_c.get(i).get("_val").toString()) ? final_values_date_c.get(i).get("_val").toString() : "0"));
            Argument d = new Argument("d = " + (jjNumber.isFloat(final_values_date_d.get(i).get("_val").toString()) ? final_values_date_d.get(i).get("_val").toString() : "0"));
            Argument e = new Argument("e = " + (jjNumber.isFloat(final_values_date_e.get(i).get("_val").toString()) ? final_values_date_e.get(i).get("_val").toString() : "0"));
            Argument f = new Argument("f = " + (jjNumber.isFloat(final_values_date_f.get(i).get("_val").toString()) ? final_values_date_f.get(i).get("_val").toString() : "0"));
            Argument g = new Argument("g = " + (jjNumber.isFloat(final_values_date_g.get(i).get("_val").toString()) ? final_values_date_g.get(i).get("_val").toString() : "0"));
            Expression exp = new Expression(indicatorRow.get(0).get(_formula).toString(), a,b,c,d, e ,f,g );
            double v = exp.calculate();
```

It works good when I change "e" to "e1" (or every thing like "x","y","z1",etc except "e") like the code below :

```
                Argument e = new Argument("e1 = " + (jjNumber.isFloat(final_values_date_e.get(i).get("_val").toString()) ? final_values_date_e.get(i).get("_val").toString() : "0"));
```

Is it Bug in library ? or is there any mistake ?

Comment: Perhaps "e" is reserved for the base of the natural logarithms 2.718....

Comment: `avoid names reserved as parser keywords, in general words known in mathematical language as function names` - from `Argument` docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps "e" is reserved for the base of the natural logarithms 2.718....

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Argument a = new Argument("a = 40.8" );
    Argument b = new Argument("b = 20.2"); 
    Expression exp = new Expression("e", a, b );
            double v = exp.calculate();
            System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$>>>>>>>" + v);

}
```

> $$$$$$$$$$$>>>>>>>2.718281828459045

Comment: e is a constant as state in [mxparser page about constant](http://mathparser.org/mxparser-math-collection/constants/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 'e' is a reserved keyword. This can be easily changed through the keyword manipulation options.

In case you want to remove just one keyword or few keywords:

```
mXparser.removeBuiltinTokens(...)
```

**API:** http://mathparser.org/api/org/mariuszgromada/math/mxparser/mXparser.html#removeBuiltinTokens-java.lang.String...-

If do not want to remove, but rather to modify the keyword

```
mXparser.modifyBuiltinToken(...)
```

**API:** http://mathparser.org/api/org/mariuszgromada/math/mxparser/mXparser.html#modifyBuiltinToken-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Additionally you can set the mXparser option indicating that you want from mXparser to always treat user keywords as more important

```
mXparser.setToOverrideBuiltinTokens()
```

**API:** http://mathparser.org/api/org/mariuszgromada/math/mxparser/mXparser.html#setToOverrideBuiltinTokens--

**See the tutorial:**
https://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/built-in-tokens-key-words-manipulation/

Additionally you are setting up your arguments using not optimal constructors - in your case much more efficient will be to use

```
public Argument​(String argumentName, double argumentValue)
```

**API:** http://mathparser.org/api/org/mariuszgromada/math/mxparser/Argument.html#Argument-java.lang.String-double-

Additionally - this software is using mXparser as well - you can learn the syntax [Scalar](https://scalarmath.org) [Calculator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mathparser.scalar.lite) [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mathparser.scalar.pro).

Best regards